# Keep delimiter in Strsplit with regex combinations

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I am munging some data that requires me to combine `regex` functions using `strsplit`. I have figured out how to split up my string, but am struggling to apply the guidance in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674503/r-strsplit-keep-delimiter-in-second-element) around keeping delimiters.

Here's an example of a string that I'm scraping:

`text<-c("This activity center is fun and helps give your birds exercise! With climbing ladders, a swing, tightrope and an assortment of engaging toys, the Activity Center has everything your bird needs to relieve stress and boredom all in one place. Relieves stress & boredom Durable & brightly colored wood Easy to clean bottom Simple installation & assemblyMaterial: WoodDimensions (Overall): 12.0 inches (H) x 15.0 inches (W) x 18.5 inches (L)Weight: 6.0 poundsHolds up to: 20.0 poundsIntended Pet Type: BirdCare and Cleaning: Hand washPet activity: ClimbTCIN: 16707835UPC: 030172025594Item Number (DPCI): 083-01-0246Report incorrect product information")`

And, here is code that successfully splits the string, but trims the delimiter:

`strsplit(as.character(free_text), "[0-9](?=[A-Z])|[a-z](?=[A-Z])|[')'](?=[A-Z])", perl=TRUE)`

As you will note, I'm looking for places where:

- Lowercase letters are directly next to uppercase letters
- Numbers next to uppercase letters
- Close-parentheses symbols next to uppercase letters

Unfortunately, the output below shows the issue with my code:

`[1] "This activity center is fun and helps give your birds exercise! With climbing ladders, a swing, tightrope and an assortment of engaging toys, the Activity Center has everything your bird needs to relieve stress and boredom all in one place. Relieves stress & boredom Durable & brightly colored wood Easy to clean bottom Simple installation & assembl"
 [2] "Material: Woo"

 [3] "Dimensions (Overall): 12.0 inches (H) x 15.0 inches (W) x 18.5 inches (L"

 [4] "Weight: 6.0 pound"

 [5] "Holds up to: 20.0 pound"

 [6] "Intended Pet Type: Bir"

 [7] "Care and Cleaning: Hand was"

 [8] "Pet activity: Clim"

 [9] "TCIN: 1670783"

[10] "UPC: 03017202559"

[11] "Item Number (DPCI): 083-01-024"

[12] "Report incorrect product information"`

i.e., the last letter is trimmed from `assemble [1]`, `Wood [2]`, and so on. How does one keep the delimiter when you are looking for regex combinations like mine?

Comment: Why didn't you put the consuming parts into lookbehinds? [`"(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\\))(?=[A-Z])"`](https://regex101.com/r/WFvy8v/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may put the consuming patterns in your regex into lookbehinds:

```
> text<-c("This activity center is fun and helps give your birds exercise! With climbing ladders, a swing, tightrope and an assortment of engaging toys, the Activity Center has everything your bird needs to relieve stress and boredom all in one place. Relieves stress & boredom Durable & brightly colored wood Easy to clean bottom Simple installation & assemblyMaterial: WoodDimensions (Overall): 12.0 inches (H) x 15.0 inches (W) x 18.5 inches (L)Weight: 6.0 poundsHolds up to: 20.0 poundsIntended Pet Type: BirdCare and Cleaning: Hand washPet activity: ClimbTCIN: 16707835UPC: 030172025594Item Number (DPCI): 083-01-0246Report incorrect product information")
> strsplit(text, "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\\))(?=[A-Z])", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
 [1] "This activity center is fun and helps give your birds exercise! With climbing ladders, a swing, tightrope and an assortment of engaging toys, the Activity Center has everything your bird needs to relieve stress and boredom all in one place. Relieves stress & boredom Durable & brightly colored wood Easy to clean bottom Simple installation & assembly"
 [2] "Material: Wood"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [3] "Dimensions (Overall): 12.0 inches (H) x 15.0 inches (W) x 18.5 inches (L)"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [4] "Weight: 6.0 pounds"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [5] "Holds up to: 20.0 pounds"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [6] "Intended Pet Type: Bird"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 [7] "Care and Cleaning: Hand wash"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [8] "Pet activity: Climb"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 [9] "TCIN: 16707835"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[10] "UPC: 030172025594"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[11] "Item Number (DPCI): 083-01-0246"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[12] "Report incorrect product information"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WFvy8v/2/) and the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/3kHktk).

The `[0-9]` is converted to `(?<=[0-9])`, `[a-z]` is now `(?<=[a-z])` and `[')']`is now `(?<=\))`.

Note that `(?<=...)` is a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches a location in a string that is immediately preceded with some pattern defined in the lookbehind.

Comment: Follow-up question (and I am more than happy to post a separate question, or modify my question above): does strsplit also allow me to send the substrings to columns when there is inconsistency in the content of the substrings? For example, I might be evaluating a second string that doesn't contain the `Material` substring. I would still want to have a `Material` column when casting to a dataframe, and the value would be NA for the string that doesn't have that substring.

Comment: @roody It definitely not possible with the splitting approach, you should consider matching, or even capturing, because the number of *captured* "fields" is always constant (the number of captures is defined by the number of capturing groups in the regex pattern). There is a nice code written by someone, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802057/regex-named-groups-in-r) if you want to follow that approach.